# history.push('/dashboard') is updating the url but not navigating to it?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

There are any questions like this in stackoverflow. But I am not able to find a solution.

Here is part of my my index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
 <Provider store={store}>
   <Login />
 </Provider>
</BrowserRouter>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This is part of my Login component

```
export default function BasicExample() {
 return (
 <Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}>
      <Dashboard />
    </Route>
    ........
  </Switch>
  </Router>
 )
}

const Login = () => {
  function handleLogin (e) {
     .....
     history.push("/dashboard");
     .....
  }
}
```

I don't know what is wrong. I am using react-admin template. Can anyone help?

Comment: are you sure `history.push` is called ? From what I can see (not much) your only error is to have Dashboard as both `component` property and children of Route (pick only one); Also calling your whole app component "Login" is probably misleading but not a technical error

Comment: Could you please show the full version of your `Login` component?

Answer (score 0):

from the doc

> that uses the HTML5 history API (pushState, replaceState and the
> popstate event) to keep your UI in sync with the URL.

I'm not seeing where you are passing/declaring the history object
in your login
You can use this:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
let history = useHistory();
```

or just use the normal router

```
import { Router } from "react-router";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory();
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Login />
    </Provider>
  </Router>,
)
```